# How to work around blocked outbound hkp port for apt keys

Tags: aptitude, gnupg

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, and need to add some apt repositories. Unfortunately, I get messages like this when running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9BF3BB4E5E17B5
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DABDBB4CEC06767
```

So, I need to install the keys for these repositories. Under 9.10 we now have the option to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvidia-vdpau/ppa
```

See [this Ubuntu help article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) for details.

This is great, except that I'm running this on a workstation behind a firewall which blocks outbound connections to pretty much all ports except those required by secretaries running Windows and IE.

The port in question here is the hkp service, port 11371.

There appear to be ways to manually download keys and install them on apt's keyring. There may even be a way to use add-apt-repository or wget or something to download a key from an alternative server making it available on port 80.

However, I haven't yet found a concise set of steps for doing so. What I'm looking for is:

1. How to find a public key for an apt-package (recommendations for resources which have these, and/or tips for searching. Searching for the key hash doesn't seem all that effective so far.)
2. How to retrieve a key (can it be done automatically using gpg or add-apt-repository?)
3. How to add a key to apt's keyring

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39):

This has been fixed in the upcoming Natty version of Ubuntu:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/software-properties/0.78.1

Those using an older version need to edit ppa.py:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py
```

Where it says:

```
keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

change to:

```
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
```

Save, exit, then you're hopefully good to go.

Comment: Awesome - solved my problem!

Comment: On 10.10, rather than editing this source file I could simply call `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys KEY_HASH`

Comment: `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80` works on 10.04 as well.

Comment: +1 for use `--keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`

Answer (score 19):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://proxy:port --recv-keys KEYID
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's one workaround I used:

I logged onto a linux server out in the free world beyond our corporate firewall, and did this:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1DABDBB4CEC06767 && gpg --export --armor 1DABDBB4CEC06767
```

Then on my workstation, I ran this, and pasted the output from the above command (the public key) into the stdin, followed by control-D:

```
sudo apt-key add -
```

Then I was able to run `sudo apt-get update` without problems.

I still think there has to be a better way, ideally something I could script.

Comment: *"I logged onto a linux server out in the free world"* It's not very likely one is able to do this in case even hkp is blocked.

Comment: ^ maybe assuming you are living in a repressive regime and not some byzantine IT department.  I can SSH anywhere I want when I'm on a VPN, but no DNS packets (and apparently no HKP.)  This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

I have another workaround here which might be handy if you can't find another linux server outside your network as proxy. Just send an email to "pgp-public-keys@pgp.mit.edu" like subject as "get 0x1DABDBB4CEC06767". But you probably still can't write a simple script to automate this.

Answer (score 5):

You could go to the web site of the keyserver, e.g. http://wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net/
Search for the key signature (you need to add 0x to the hex signature) i.e. 0x1DABDBB4CEC06767.

Click on the link you'll hopefully get and paste the text into a file on the machine, i.e.

```
cat > <filename>

[PASTE]

[Ctrl-C]
```

Then

```
apt-key add <filename>
```

This worked fine for me; it appears my work proxy blocks a lot of "non-standard" ports.

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me. My proxy is heavily blocking the hkp protocol, and even if I use port 80, gpg still times out contacting a server. This way I was finally able to add the key.

Answer (score 4):

I found a neat way of doing it in a single command through port 80 which is always open for www traffic.

http://gurrier.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/downlolading-repo-keys-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall/

Comment: apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser. When answering questions, please respond to the question with the solution in the reply itself. There is no guarantee that the site you referred to will keep the site up and if it goes down, then your answer will be worthless.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 some_ppa
```

The secure https (outgoing 443) would not be blocked by the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use ssh to forward the port to an external host then run the `apt-add-repo` command.

```
ssh -fqTnN -D 11371 <user@host>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with gpg. The workaround with adding the port to the server name worked by editing my `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file. However, I'm still going to ask our sysadmin to open outbound port 11371, so I don't have to worry about this again.

Comment: _The_ port? How does specifying the port (11371) in the config work around the firewall?