# GPG error when updating Linux Mint 9

Tags: linux, updates, linux-mint, apt-get

When i run `sudo apt-get update`, i get the following error

> `W: GPG error:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid
>   Release: The following signatures
>   couldn't be verified because the
>   public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
>   9BDB3D89CE49EC21`.

I tried searching for it, but wasn't able to find anything helpful. What is the reason for this, and how can i fix this?

Edit1: I am using Linux mint 9.

Edit2: On `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu`, I was getting `gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host`, so i did according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/64922/how-to-work-around-blocked-outbound-hkp-port-for-apt-keys/127930#127930) post. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it gives no errors. But, firefox 5 is still not installed. In my update manager when I try to install, it says "Fix broken packages first". In Synaptic manager there is an option of "Fix broken Packages", but it does nothing. What is going wrong here?

Edit3: **Update** is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources, and **Upgrade** is used to install latest versions. So, I was forgetting about upgrade!

Thanks!

Comment: try this: apt-get --fix-broken

Comment: @Sunny : `--fix-broken` is to be used with one command, right? I used it as `apt-get --fix-broken update`, still firefox is not updated.

Comment: This occurs today, with Linux Mint 17.2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list, and comment out the offending line (add "#" at the beginning of the line). The line you are looking for should have "ppa" in it. Save the file. Pls - note which ppa was mentioned there.

If in sources.list there is no ppa mentioned, check the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ for a file which has "ppa" mentioned in there". Move this file to somewhere (so you have backup).

Then do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:any-ppa-that-I-need
```

This will add the ppa back to sources, but will fetch and install the pgp key as well.

Comment: How to know which ppa to add? Currently in my sources.list file there is no ppa. But in the directory sources.list.d there is `mozillateam-firefox-stable-lucid.list` which has ppa in it.

Comment: then just move this file out (so you have backup): mv mozillateam-firefox-stable-lucid.list ~, then add the repo again. (see the exact ppa name in that file).

Comment: Please take a look at my edit2.

Comment: Thanks! With your method, I was able to update my system.

Comment: Fails in Linux Cinnamon Mint 17.2 64-bit with
> Cannot add PPA: 'No JSON object could be decoded'.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct method is to use `apt` itself:

> $ apt-key update

---

The Ubuntu Forums have a couple things to say about this using more roundabout methods, if apt doesn't do it properly.

> ok. I figured it out.
>
> do this:
>
> wget
>   http://packages.freecontrib.org/ubuntu/plf/12B83718.gpg
>
> and then open up synaptic and go to
>   settings>repos>authentication and
>   "import file key" browse the key and
>   click ok.
>
> and then sudo aptitude update

---

And this:

> sudo wget http://ftp-master.debian.org/ziyi_key_2006.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -

---

This is the [link](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=apt-get+no+public+key) to my Google search - there's quite a bit much there to put in a single response.

Comment: `apt-key update` does nothing. The second link that you gave, when I run wget, I get `ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.` and the last link that you gave, on wget I get `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Please take a look at edit2.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [ChrisJean.com](https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/) I fixed this entirely in about 10 minutes.

First, collect a list of the GPG errors, by
`cd /etc/apt/sources/list/d`
`sudo apt-get update > listoferrors`

Do `sudo nano listoferrors` and strip out everything but the 16 character hexadecimal strings, and a space between each, then add at the beginning
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys` 
so the hex strings, with a space between each, follow that apt-key command.

Copy the entire string and paste it into a terminal window with Ctrl-Shift-V. You end up with something like
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0123456789ABCDEF FEDCBA9876543210 11A11B11C11D11E1`

Run it. It goes out, retrieves the correct keys, and puts them in place.

Then, another `sudo apt-get update` runs without flaw.

Close and delete the `listoferrors` file.